# Prolog get every second Item in a list

Tags: list, prolog

I want to write a Prolog predicate
evenElement(List,Term) which shoud suceed if the EvenElement is equal to Term

So far I have this code

```
evenElement(L,TERM) :- evenElement_rec(L,TERM).
evenElement_rec([],0).
evenElement_rec([_,HEven|T],TERM):-
    evenElement_rec(T,TERM),
    isEqual(HEven,TERM).
isEqual(A,B) :- A is B.
```

isEqual is never called, what do I have to change that this will be executed?

output is:

```
 trace,evenElement([1,2,3,4,5,6], 4).
    Call: (7) evenElement([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 4) ? creep
    Call: (8) evenElement_rec([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 4) ? creep
    Call: (9) evenElement_rec([3, 4, 5, 6], 4) ? creep
    Call: (10) evenElement_rec([5, 6], 4) ? creep
    Call: (11) evenElement_rec([], 4) ? creep
    Fail: (11) evenElement_rec([], 4) ? creep
    Fail: (10) evenElement_rec([5, 6], 4) ? creep
    Fail: (9) evenElement_rec([3, 4, 5, 6], 4) ? creep
    Fail: (8) evenElement_rec([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 4) ? creep
    Fail: (7) evenElement([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 4) ? creep
false.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are writing a Prolog predicate, you could start like in other programming languages, digging immediately into the very problem. Or you can first think about the relation, and consider something simpler i.e. *more general*.  You want that the first argument is a list, and the second argument is an "even" element — I assume you meant an element occurring at an even position. That is:

```
list_evenelement(L, E) :-
   nth1(I,L,E),
   I mod 2 =:= 0.
```

But, say you want to implement that yourself. We might start with a generalization. In this case: `list_element/2` which is true for all elements:

```
list_element([E|_], E).
list_element([_|Es], E) :-
   list_element(Es, E).
```

That is almost what you want. Except that it is a bit too general. That is, the set of solutions contains also answers you do not like. In particular, the first element, should not be part of the solutions.  You have thus to specialize that program. We can specialize a program by adding a goal or by removing a clause (which is tantamount to adding **`false`**). Removing the fact, however, goes too far - there will no longer be any solution.

I will try it differently, and **unfold** the definition like so:

```
list_element([E|_], E).
list_element([_|Es], E) :-
   list_element2(Es, E).

list_element2([E|_], E).
list_element2([_|Es], E) :-
   list_element(Es, E).
```

That should be still our good olde definition that is too general. Now, however, we can insert **`false`**!

```
list_element([E|_], E) :- false.
list_element([_|Es], E) :-
   list_element2(Es, E).

list_element2([E|_], E).
list_element2([_|Es], E) :-
   list_element(Es, E).
```

This remaining part is our sought after definition, you can also put it more compactly:

```
list_evenelement([_,E|_], E).
list_evenelement([_,_|Es], E) :-
   list_evenelement(Es, E).
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks way more complicated than it has any right to be from your problem statement

> I want to write a Prolog predicate evenElement(List,Term) which shoud suceed if the EvenElement is equal to Term.

Assuming that you're numbering your list elements relative to one, so for the list `[a,b,c,d]`, the odd elements (1st and 3rd) are `a` and `c` respectively and the event elements (2nd and 4th) are `b` and `d` (rather than zero-relative, where `a` would be the zeroth element and `c` the 2nd, something like this will do. We look at the list, 2 elements at a time:

```
even_element( [_,T|Xs] , T ) . 
even_element( [_,_|Xs] , T ) :-
  even_element( Xs , T ) .
```